# Text Change Event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, textbox, onkeydown

I have two textboxes, Text1 and Text2, in an Update Panel.  The code is here:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panle" >
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate> 
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and I have wrote this code on `textchanged` event of Text1:

```
  Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
    End Sub
```

Now the problem is that when I enter the text in Text1, and then Press enter to then the text of text2 is equal to text of text1, but i want to do this before pressing the enter in text1.  I mean as i key down in text1 then the text of text2 should equal to text2.

Comment: Look into `knockout.js` as it excels at this sort of thing.

Comment: ontextchanged only fires after you leave the field, whether it is an enter or clicking elsewhere on the page. you are best off using javascript (jquery) to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle the keydown event, you need javascript:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onkeydown="document.getElementById('TextBox2').value=this.value" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use JQuery to do what you want.

```
$('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').keyup(function(event) {
   var value = $(this).val();
   $('#<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>').text(value);
});
```

Since you handle the problem at client side, you don't need to set `AutoPostBack` to True anymore.

Answer (score 0):

.aspx page

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function chngtxtbxval()
    {
      var t1=document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
      var t2=document.getElementById("TextBox2");
      t2.value=t1;

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

codebehind page

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "chngtxtbxval();");
    }
```